# When injecting a constructor in spring, how do you know and inject if the parameter is a list object?

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

I know how to inject and use beans in the factory pattern.
When injecting a constructor in spring, how do you know and inject if the parameter is a list object?

```
@Component
public class SampleFactory {
  private final Map<SampleType, SampleHandler> sampleHandlerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public SampleFactory(List<SampleHandler> sampleHandlers) { // How does spring know here and inject it into a list?
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sampleHandlers)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No sampleHandler exists");
    }

    for (SampleHandler sampleHandler: sampleHandlers) {
      this.sampleHandlerMap.put(sampleHandler.getSampleType, sampleHandler);
    }
  }

  public SampleHandler getHandler(SampleType sampleType) {
    return sampleHandlerMap.get(sampleType);
  }
}
```

The sample handler was created with 3 beans as shown below.

```
@Component
public class SampleHandlerA implements SampleHandler {
   ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class SampleHandlerB implements SampleHandler {
   ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class SampleHandlerC implements SampleHandler {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Spring has specific logic that recognizes `Collection`, `List`, or `Set` and interprets those as "there may be several beans that match, so give me all of them".

Comment: what exactly is your question? how Spring achieves that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your question: "how do you know and inject if the parameter is a list object?"

   - If you want to know when to use list, You should use list/collection when you see possibility of multiple beans of same type.
   - If you are not sure that bean will be present in context then you should use Optional
2. Your question in code: "How does spring know here and inject it into a list?"

   - Spring knows that it is a list because you defined the type of constructor parameter as List
   - In any Spring bean, if only one constructor is present then no need to write on top of constructor/arguments the `@Autowired`, Spring will automatically do the injection using that constructor.[Refer Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Comment: 3 code implementing SampleHandler is created as List, and is Spring injecting this List into the constructor?

Comment: All Spring Beans which are implementing SampleHandler will be injected in the list.